# facing problem installing react native: Cannot find module ...\node_modules\lru-cache\dist\cjs\index.js

Tags: react-native, npm-install, npx

I've been encountering some difficulties while trying to install React Native. Whenever I attempt to set up React Native on my system, I encounter an error message

The error message I'm receiving is

> [Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\path-scurry\node_modules\lru-cache\dist\cjs\index.js'].

Despite trying various troubleshooting methods, I haven't been successful in resolving the issue.

How to troubleshoot and resolve this installation problem?

[image]